# Creating jar with external dependencies and other jars in Maven

Tags: java, maven, build, executable-jar

Step 1 : I have a Utils.jar that I have to include in my Project1. I need the Utils.jar to contain all the maven dependencies within itself so that I don't have to specify the same in Project1 pom.xml.

Step 2 : I need to create Project1.jar and include it in Project2. I again need a way such that I do not replicate the pom of Project1.jar in Project2 pom.xml. Also, I need the Project1.jar to include Utils.jar so that I don't have to add Utils.jar to Project2.

What is the right way to do this?

I looked into the Maven assembly plugin, but it requires specifying the Main class. I do not have a main class in my Utils project. I am not sure what I am missing.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is called an uber jar or fat jar. Here is an article on how to do it.

https://www.mkyong.com/maven/create-a-fat-jar-file-maven-assembly-plugin/

Hope it helps

p.s. main class is not needed except for when you need to make the jar executable.

Answer (score 0):

It is normally not a good idea to build a `utils.jar` as fat jar (containing the dependencies).

If you add a dependency to `utils.jar` in Project1, then all dependencies of `utils.jar` become dependencies of Project1 *automatically*. This is the Maven dependency resolution. You do not need to copy or retype the dependencies of `utils.jar` in Project1.